# What the purpose of currency attribute in Shopify's shipping rates response?

Tags: shopify

According to CarrierService API docs shipping rates response should contain the currency attribute: http://docs.shopify.com/api/carrierservice

The shipping rates example response below still cause Shopify to displays all three in USD (or what ever default store currency is) during checkout, with no conversion, i.e. $12.95 and $29.34 for EUR and GBP accordingly.

```
{
  "rates" => [
    {
      'service_name' => 'Method A',
      'service_code' => 'RMG9A',
      'total_price' => '1295', # cents
      'currency' => 'EUR',
      'min_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400',
      'max_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400'
    },
    {
      'service_name' => 'Method B',
      'service_code' => 'RMG1P',
      'total_price' => '2934', # cents
      'currency' => 'GBP',
      'min_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400',
      'max_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400'
    },
    {
      'service_name' => 'Method C',
      'service_code' => 'RMG1D',
      'total_price' => '2934', # cents
      'currency' => 'USD',
      'min_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400',
      'max_delivery_date' => '2013-07-13 14:48:45 -0400'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: interesting, I've tested today again and looks like it works, i.e. converting total_price according to store currency

Comment: anyway would be nice to get some insight on which rates actually used, which bank or service?